# Помогите найти ошибку или скиньте свой код задача по проге на с++

Tags: c++

вот мой код выдает что правильно лишь 88% на каких тестах я хз-

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>

 using namespace std;

 int main(){
 float Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy, Dx, Dy, AD, DC, AB, CB, DB;
cin >> Ax >> Ay >> Bx >> By >> Cx >> Cy >> Dx >> Dy;
AD = sqrt((Ax-Dx)*(Ax-Dx)+(Ay-Dy)*(Ay-Dy));
DC = sqrt((Dx-Cx)*(Dx-Cx)+(Dy-Cy)*(Dy-Cy));
AB = sqrt((Ax-Bx)*(Ax-Bx)+(Ay-By)*(Ay-By));
CB = sqrt((Cx-Bx)*(Cx-Bx)+(Cy-By)*(Cy-By));
DB = sqrt((Dx-Bx)*(Dx-Bx)+(Dy-By)*(Dy-By));
if (AD == DC && (AD*AD+DB*DB-AB*AB)/(2*AD*DB) == (DC*DC+DB*DB-CB*CB)/(2*DC*DB) && AD/AB == DC/CB) cout << "all";
else {
         if (AD == DC) cout << "median";
         else { if ((AD*AD+DB*DB-AB*AB)/(2*AD*DB) == (DC*DC+DB*DB-CB*CB)/(2*DC*DB)) cout << "altitude"; 
                else {
                        if(AD/AB == DC/CB) cout << "bisector";
                       else cout << "cevian"; }
              }
              
     }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Целые числа помещаются во `float`. Последующие вычисления приводят к ошибкам округления. Сравнение вещественных чисел на равенство просто не имеет смысла в этой задаче. Вы ожидаете что всё будет округляться одинаково?

Comment: Переписывайте все соотношения в целых числах.

Comment: не работает значение косинуса может быть вещественным

Comment: предложите своё решение

Comment: В коде, который вы написали, где косинус вычисляется? Почитайте ваш код ещё раз.

Comment: Я выскажусь, не обижайтесь. Выглядит так что вы позаимствовали код, не прочитав его толком. Прочитайте, в коде из вопроса задача уже решена почти в целых числах. Осталось сделать несколько алгебраических преобразований, сменить типы и всё заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно математичесое решение, особенно, если задача математическая. Тут не нужно считать  размеры отрезков, а нужно лишь проверить на равенство абсцисс и ординат трех точек. Если например абсцисы точек A, D, C равны,  значит нужно сравнивать их ординаты. Если ордината точки D есть среднее арифметическое `Dy == (Ay + Cy)/2`то и на треугольнике она будет в середине, то есть BD есть медиана. Такой же логикой строить алгоритм проверки остальных условий. Прошло  больше 40 лет, что я окончил школу, но, по моему в школьных учебниках все это должно быть, а если нет, то не трудно самым придумать как проверить схожесть треугольников BCD и ABD, зная только их координаты. То есть нужно использовать тот факт, что  если взять только  абсциссы или ординаты(если абсциссы равны) трех  точек на прямой, то соотношение образуемых отрезков  точно такое же, что и соотношение отрезков на прямой.